# Compare old and new file pushed to git repository with (preferably) python hook

Tags: python, git

I am sorry if this has been asked before, but I still can't find a clear answer whether what I need to do is possible or not. Now what I need to do:

I need to let people clone file, which contains unique (key, value) pairs, modify this file (do anything to the values, but only add keys) and then push it back to git repo. Is there a way how I could check both files together (i.e. load the old file to memory to check keys weren't modified the list with what was added? I thought git could be suitable for this as I won't have to take care about implementing history of changes, diffs etc.

I already explored git hooks, but none of the server-side hooks I found seems to be able to do this (read whole file), as the pre-receive hook only receives changes and post-receive can't block the push.

I have one idea: split the file in two, one only with keys (and pre-receive check there are no modified lines, only new ones) and another one with whole pairs, where any modifications can be done. However, I don't know how to ensure integrity of the keys in both files.

Any hints or better ideas please?

Comment: Quick and dirty: A hook that checks that the diff of a commit has no `-` lines.

Comment: Tried to answer as best as I understand. I think you will need to be more clear about what you need, in what context it is going to be used. the "do not touch the old ones" comment for instance could mean you don't want users to remove lines, but this can be covered by agreeing with users not to do it. Or as Biffen suggests you can enforce it using a pre commit hook. If it isn't relevant to the question you ask, remove it :)

Comment: Thanks, agreeing with users is possible, but I thought a fool-proof server-side solution would be better to prevent users from making unintentional mistakes.

Check there are no `-` lines seems good provided I split the file to two (I modified OP to specify there are untouchable "keys" and editable "values".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can check this in the `pre-receive` hook.  The input to this hook is a list of lines of the form

```
<old-sha1> <new-sha1> <ref name>
```

and might look like this

```
fa84d9ae4374c8675191e003565ad197e9584737 619afe11d5e85c192fb2bea066d214065c50b561 /refs/head/master
```

For each of the refs you want to check, you can get the contents of both versions of the file by using

```
git cat-file blob <sha1>:path/to/file
```

This allows you to compute and compare the set of keys, and refuse the update by returning a non-zero error code if desired.

Since the `pre-receive` hook can only refuse all ref updates or none of them, you could also implement this in the `update` hook, which gets called once per ref that is updated.